# Minimax algorithm in Ruby in Object-Oriented way

Tags: ruby, algorithm, oop, minimax, minmax

I am trying to implement minimax algorithm for a tic tac toe game in an object-oriented way. I was a bit stuck with how to deal with reverting the state for my `board` object once the algorithm determined the best move. When running the program, I have noticed that `minimax` method operated on the current `board` object which is not ideal.

I added a method to undo the move done by the `minimax` method: `board.[]=(empty_square, Square::INITIAL_MARKER)`

I have noticed the algorithm makes the wrong choice. Here, `X` is a player and `O` is a computer. If this is the state of the `board`:

```
     |     |
     |     |   
     |     |
-----+-----+-----
     |     |
     |  X  |   
     |     |
-----+-----+-----
     |     |
     |     |  O
     |     |
```

When the player `X` makes a move and picks square `2`, minimax (computer, `O`) will choose `7` instead of `8` which would be a better choice:

```
     |     |
     |  X  |   
     |     |
-----+-----+-----
     |     |
     |  X  |   
     |     |
-----+-----+-----
     |     |
  O  |     |  O
     |     |
```

Due to my inexperience, I am a little bit lost on how to proceed and would appreciate any guidance!

Here is the `minimax` method:

```rb
  def minimax
    best_move = 0
    score_current_move = nil
    best_score = -10000 if @current_marker == COMPUTER_MARKER
    best_score = 10000 if @current_marker == HUMAN_MARKER
    board.unmarked_keys.each do |empty_square|
      board.[]=(empty_square, @current_marker)
      if board.full?
        score_current_move = 0
      elsif board.someone_won?
        score_current_move = -1 if board.winning_marker == HUMAN_MARKER
        score_current_move = 1 if board.winning_marker == COMPUTER_MARKER
      else
        alternate_player
        score_current_move = minimax[0]
      end
      if ((@current_marker == COMPUTER_MARKER) && (score_current_move >= best_score))
        best_score = score_current_move
        best_move = empty_square
      elsif ((@current_marker == HUMAN_MARKER) && (score_current_move <= best_score))
        best_score = score_current_move
        best_move = empty_square
      end
      board.[]=(empty_square, Square::INITIAL_MARKER)
    end
    [best_score, best_move]
  end
```

Comment: Could you condense your problem a bit so that it is not required to read and understand 350 lines of code? Please try to reduce it to a minimal example showing your problem. Then describe exactly what you want to achieve, what exactly does not work with your current code (do you see incorrect behavior, exceptions / errors, anything else?). Please be as specific as possible and include any error messages and example code to specifically show your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some guidelines. You can edit your question with the edit link below it.

Comment: You might want to look into defining a `initialize_copy` method for your clas(ses), which shoud alter the behaviour of `dup`.

Answer (score 0):

I see no particular advantage here to defining any classes at all. There is only one board and only two players (the machine and the human) who operate quite differently.

**Main method**

Next I will write the main method, which depends on several helper methods, all of which could be *private*.

```
def play_game(human_moves_first = true)
  raise ArgumentError unless [true, false].include?(human_moves_first)
  human_marker, machine_marker = 
    human_moves_first ? ['X', 'O'] : ['O', 'X']
  board = Array.new(9)

  if human_moves_first
    display(board)
    human_to_move(board, 'X')
  end

  loop do
    display(board)
    play = machine_best_play(board, machine_marker)   
    board[play] = machine_marker
    display(board)
    if win?(board)
      puts "Computer wins"
      break
    end
    if tie?(board)
      puts "Tie game"
      break
    end
    human_to_move(board, human_marker)
    if tie?(board)
      puts "Tie game"
      break
    end
  end
end
```

As you see I have provided a choice of who starts, the machine or the human.

Initially, `board` is an array of `9` `nil`s.

The method simply loops until a determination is made as to whether the machine wins or there is a tie. As we know, the machine, acting logically, cannot lose. In each pass of the loop the machine makes a mark. If that results in a win or a tie the game is over; else the human is called upon to make a mark.

Before considering the method `machine_best_play`, let's consider a few simple helper method that are needed.

**Simple helper methods**

I will demonstrate these methods with `board` defined as follows:

```
board = ['X', 'O', 'X',
         nil, 'O', nil,
         nil, nil, 'X']
```

Note that while the human refers to the nine locations as `1` through `9`, internally they they are represented as indices of `board`, `0` through `8`.

*Determine unmarked cells*

```
def unmarked_cells(board)
  board.each_index.select { |i| board[i].nil? }
end
```

```
unmarked_cells(board)
  #=> [3, 5, 6, 7]
```

*Ask human to make a selection*

```
def human_to_move(board, marker)
  loop do
    puts "Please mark '#{marker}' in an unmarked cell"
    cell = gets.chomp
    if (n = Integer(cell, exception: false)) && n.between?(1, 9)
      n -= 1 # convert to index in board
      if board[n].nil?
        board[n] = marker
        break
      else
        puts "That cell is occupied"
      end
    else
      puts "That is not a number between 1 and 9"
    end
  end
end
```

```
human_to_move(board, 'O')  
Please mark an 'O' in an unmarked cell
```

If `cell = gets.chomp #=> "6"` then

```
board
  #=> ["X", "O", "X", nil, "O", "O", nil, nil, "X"]
```

For the following I have set `board` to its original value above.

*Display the board*

```
def display(board)
  board.each_slice(3).with_index do |row, idx|
    puts   "     |     |"
    puts "  #{row.map { |obj| obj || ' ' }.join('  |  ')}"
    puts "     |     |"
    puts "-----+-----+-----" unless idx == 2
  end
end
```

```
display(board)
     |     |
  X  |  O  |  X
     |     |
-----+-----+-----
     |     |
     |  O  |   
     |     |
-----+-----+-----
     |     |
     |     |  X
     |     |
```

*Determine if the last move (by the machine or human) wins*

```
WINNING_CELL_COMBOS = [
  [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]
]
```

```
def win?(board)
  WINNING_CELL_COMBOS.any? do |arr|
    (f = arr.first) != nil && arr == [f,f,f]
  end
end
```

```
win? board
  #=> false
```

```
win? ['X', nil, 'O', 'nil', 'X', 'O', nil, nil, 'X']
  #=> true
```

```
win? ['X', nil, 'O', 'nil', 'X', 'O', 'X', nil, 'O']
  #=> true
```

*Determine if game ends in a tie*

```
def tie?(board)
  unmarked_cells(board).empty?
end
```

```
tie?(board)
  #=> false
```

```
tie? ['X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X',  'O', 'O']
  #=> true
```

Note `unmarked_cells.empty?` can be replaced with `board.all?`.

**Determine machine's best play using minimax algorithm**

```
MACHINE_WINS = 0
TIE = 1
MACHINE_LOSES = 2
NEXT_MARKER = { "X"=>"O", "O"=>"X" }

def machine_best_play(board, marker)
  plays = open_cells(board)
  plays.min_by |play|
    board_after_play = board.dup.tap { |a| a[play] = marker }
    if machine_wins?(board_after_play, marker)
      MACHINE_WIN
    elsif plays.size == 1
      TIE
    else
      human_worst_outcome(board_after_play, NEXT_MARKER[marker]) 
    end
  end
end
```

This requires two more methods.

*Determine machine's best worst outcome for current state of `board`*

```
def machine_worst_outcome(board, marker)
  plays = open_cells(board)
  plays.map |play|
    board_after_play = board.dup.tap { |a| a[play] = marker }
    if win?(board_after_play)
      MACHINE_WINS
    elsif plays.size == 1
      TIE
    else
      human_worst_outcome(board_after_play, NEXT_MARKER[marker]) 
    end
  end.min
end
```

*Determine human's best worst outcome for current state of board assuming
human also plays a minimax strategy*

```
def human_worst_outcome(board, marker)
  plays = open_cells(board)
  plays.map |play|
    board_after_play = board.dup.tap { |a| a[play] = marker }
    if win?(board_after_play)
      MACHINE_LOSES
    elsif plays.size == 1
      TIE
    else
      machine_worst_outcome(board_after_play, NEXT_MARKER[marker])
    end
  end.max
end
```

Notice that the human *maximizes* the worst outcome from the machine's perspective whereas the machine *minimizes* its worst outcome.

**Almost there**

All that remains is to quash any bugs that are present. Being short of time at the moment I will leave that to you, should you wish to do so. Feel free to edit my answer to make any corrections.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer! The challenge with OOP is that it is not very straightforward to duplicate the board states. I managed to implement the algorithm in a functional way, but not OOP way. Just curious how it can be done in OOP. Thank you! I already improved my algorithm and implemented a method to undo the move. Now I see that my algorithm just chooses the best move, but not the best worst move.